# about parent object's init method

Tags: ios

Parent.h (extends NSObject)
like this:

```
@implementation InTParent

-(id)init
{
    NSLog(@"Parent init method");
    if (self = [super init]) {
        ;
    }
    return self;
}


-(id)initWithName:(NSString*)name;
{
    NSLog(@"Parent initWithName method");
    if (self = [self init]) {
        ;
    } 
    return self;
}
```

Son.h(extends Parent)
like this:

```
@implementation InTSon

-(id)init
{
    NSLog(@"Son init method");
    if (self = [super init]) {
        ;
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithName:(NSString*)name;
{
    NSLog(@"Son initWithName method");
    if (self = [super initWithName:name]) {
        ;
    }
    return self;
}
```

I use this: `IntSon *_son = [[IntSon alloc] initWithName:@"asd"];`

why the output is:
Son initWithName method --> Parent initWithName method --> Son init method --> Parent init method

But in Java,it perhaps like this :
Son initWithName method --> Parent initWithName method --> Parent init method

Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

To understand this behavior, you have to understand how Objective-C message dispatching works. And this is a good example to illustrate it.

At a high level, any time you call a method on any object, the Objective-C runtime looks for the implementation provided the most-derived (deepest in the class hierarchy) class. If it doesn't find it, it will go the next most-derived, and so on all they way up to `NSObject`. The first time it finds an implementation matching the selector (method name, roughly), it will execute that implementation. When you call `super`, you are specifying to send a message to the next most-derived class's implementation of that method.

So in your code, you call `alloc` on the `InTSon` class, which returns an instance of `IntSon` with the `isa` pointer set to the class object `InTSon`. The `isa` pointer is how method implementations are looked for during the process of ascending the class hierarchy.

So after you have an `InTSon` instance, you call `initWithName:` on it, and it checks the class pointed to by `isa` (which is `InTSon` for an implementation of this method. It finds it, so executes it, resulting in your first output:

`"Son initWithName method"`

Immediately afterward, you call the superclass implementation of that method, which looks in `InTParent` for its implementation of `initWithName:` and executes that code, resulting in your second output:

`Parent initWithName method`

Now here is where you see a deviation from Java - you call `init` on `self`. `self`, however, is a pointer to an `InTSon` instance. So when the runtime resolves this message, it looks first for the implementation of `init` in the `InTSon` class. Of course, it finds it, and executes the code for that method, which gives you your third output, `Son init method`. Next you call super, which looks up and executes the `InTParent` implementation of `init`, and gives you your final output.

To sum up, regardless of **where** in the class hierarchy a method is called from, if it's called on `self`, it will **always** execute the most derived implementation of that method. Hope this helps, and if you have any questions please let me know!

Comment: @Swu_Log you're welcome! Did this help you out or do you still need more help?

Comment: Yes,thanks a lot, not a english mothortoungue people,so I am trying my best to understand it!

Answer (score 1):

Your class diagram looks like this:

[image: class diagram]

When you send the `initWithName:` message to your instance of `InTSon`, the system looks up the method in `InTSon`'s method table, and finds the method that we call `-[InTSon initWithName:]`.  That method, simplified, looks like this:

```
// -[InTSon initWithName:]
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name {
    return [super initWithName:name];
}
```

This method does `[super initWithName:name]`.  Because it sends the message to `super`, the system looks in the method table of the superclass of `self`'s class. Your object's class is `InTSon`, and its superclass is `InTParent`.  So when `-[InTSon initWithName:]` does `[super initWithName:name]`, the system looks for the method in `InTParent`'s method table.  It finds the method that we call `-[InTParent initWithName:]`.  That method, simplified, looks like this:

```
// -[InTParent initWithName:]
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name {
    return [self init];
}
```

This method does `[self init]`.  Because it sends the message to `self`, the system looks in the method table for `self`'s class.  Even though we are in `-[InTParent initWithName:]`, **`self` is still an instance of the `InTSon` class**.  So the system looks for an `init` method in `InTSon`'s method table.  It finds the method we call `-[InTSon init]`.  That method, simplified, looks like this:

```
// -[InTSon init]
- (id)init {
    return [super initWithName:@"sdas"];
}
```

This method does `[super initWithName:]`, so the system looks in the superclass's (`InTParent`'s) method table and finds the `-[InTParent initWithName:]` method.  And as we have just seen, `-[InTParent initWithName:]` ends up calling `[InTSon init]`.  So we get infinite recursion and the app crashes.

To solve this problem, you need to pick one of `InTParent`'s init methods as its **designated initializer**.  [You should read about designated initializers in Apple's documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MultipleInitializers.html)

You should pick the `initWithName:` method as `InTParent`'s designated initializer.  This method must **not** send any init message to `self`.  It should **only** send super's designated initializer message (which in the case of `NSObject` is the `init` message), and it should send it to `super`.  So you need to write the `-[InTParent initWithName:]` method like this:

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name {
    // init is NSObject's designated initializer, and we send it to super.
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        // your initialization code here
    }
    return self;
}
```

By picking a designated initializer, and making your designated initializer only send the superclass's designated initializer message to `super`, you prevent the infinite recursion.

Comment: Thanks very much!!!
I think "self is still an instance of the InTSon class. " works!

Answer (score 0):

Because "self" is a "InTSon", so [self init] calls the "InTSon" init method.